# Their body? their bodies?

Tags: plural-forms, singular-they

> 1. They should remove toxins from their bodies.
> 2. They should remove toxins from their body.

I am confused about these two sentences above.
I think the first sentence is correct because 'their' means more than one person and the body must be more than one.
However, I wonder if their bodies could mean each person has more than one body.
The reason I ask this question is because of the sentence below.

> Frogs spend most of their life in water.

If 'their bodies' is correct, Should 'their life' in this sentence be 'their lives' because 'frogs' is plural?

Comment: Both are correct. The intent is obvious, and both are technically ambiguous, but not practically or realistically ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the original statements can be correct, depending on the circumstances surrounding the statement.

If many people have been poisoned and can do so, then

> *they* [plural] *should remove toxins from their bodies*

as you state, because there are many bodies owned between many people.

However, if a singular person of unknown gender has been poisoned can so so, then

> *they* [singular indeterminate person] *should remove toxins from their body*.

The Frog statement is slightly less ambiguous, however, and your reasoning is correct.

> Frogs spend most of their lives in water.

because there are many frogs with many lives between them.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very clear and I have learned new things from you.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the sentence "Frogs spend most of their life in water" is also correct, it doesn't mean all the frogs on earth share the same life. Saying that, I do prefer the plural form "lives".

Comment: I did look at putting in in a more comprehensive answer, stating that some people would accept the plural/singular rather than just the plural/plural, but that the general acceptance would be plural/plural, but thought that would cloud the issue. :)

Comment: If you skip something and avoid the more comprehensive answer, you can almost bet someone will add a comment and provide an additional clarification. @Mari-LouA is one of our better members about such things; she authors a lot of helpful comments.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. They should remove toxins from their body.
> 2. They should remove toxins from their bodies.

If the entities *(they)* share a common body then the 1-st is correct otherwise the 2-nd is correct. Notice that "**their**" can either mean their own body(ies) or some body(ies) belonging to them.

- They should remove toxins from their body. *(Several men should remove toxins from a body of another man. The body belongs to the several men.)*
- They should remove toxins from their body. *(Several men should remove toxins from a single body of theirs)* - **This is illogical**.

> "*To talk about several people each doing the same thing, English usually prefers a plural noun for the repeated idea. Plural forms are almost always used in this case if there are possessives.*" Practical English Usage by Michael Swan, entry #530.1 AND: "*After a plural possessive we do not normally use a singular noun in the sense of '**one each**'.*" same, entry #441.4. This is called the '**distributive use**'.

---

As for the "**frogs**" example. The sentence is speaking about the life of the species not individual frogs.

- Frogs spend most of their life in water. *(Each frog within the species "frogs" spends its life in water)*

This can apply even to a particular group or subset.

- Cave frogs spend most of their life in dark caves.

The easy way to understand it is to take a loving couple and imagine them either as a couple or as separate individuals:

- Their life is full of adventures. *(They both share one life)*
- Their lives are full of adventures. *(Each of them has their own life)*

Comment: Your illogical example could work, though, if "body" was used more figuratively. For example, sometimes a church congregation is referred to as a church "body". If people who were sowing seeds of discord among the group were labeled as "toxins," then one could well write, "They should remove toxins from their body."

Comment: Don't forget that "they" can be singular, in the case when you don't want to specify a gender.  *"Each person was told, individually, that they should remove toxins from their body."*  It's not an ideal phrasing, but it is possible.