# Guys are allowed to bring their girlfriend/girlfriends to the event. - are both ok?

Tags: usage, singular-vs-plural

**Example 1**

> Guys are allowed to bring their **girlfriend** to the event.

**Example 2**

> Guys are allowed to bring their **girlfriends** to the event.

Are both of them acceptable?

I don't know why some people use Example 1 instead of Example 2.

Can somebody explain?

Comment: Related: [They write in their school diary (or) diaries?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110914/they-write-in-their-school-diary-or-diaries)

Comment: Also: [Is it grammatically correct: no one raised their hand?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/260982/is-it-grammatically-correct-no-one-raised-their-hand) and [Their body? their bodies?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151814/)

Comment: I think that Mari-Lou has a duplicate.  Do you agree.?

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is correct, because example 2 could be interpreted as men bringing multiple girlfriends, which is not possible. Why introduce ambiguity when the first sentence is accurate? Therefore, use the first sentence.

"Guys are allowed to bring their girlfriend to the event" means guys (all the guys, so each guy) are allowed to bring their girlfriend. Each guy is allowed to bring his girlfriend. Of course, guys are not sharing a single girlfriend, so there is no ambiguity possible in example 1.

However, they will both be understood as "each man is allowed to bring his girlfriend," so it doesn't really matter that much.

Comment: *men bringing multiple girlfriends, which is not possible*  Ummm... really?  Believing that would be a BigMistake, indeed!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Yes. The speaker is clearly trying to say that each man may bring his girlfriend. The intent of the question is non-ambiguous.

Comment: That's a likely assumption, but we don't know the speaker, so it can only remain an assumption.  But I'm clearly making light of your claim that men cannot possibly have multiple girlfriends... heck, many have multiple wives! (And even more have a wife and multiple girlfriends! Who are they allowed to bring?)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Presumably, if they are somewhere where English is spoken and they bring multiple wives, they should read the Edmunds Act (or similarly applicable act in their country) before they end up in jail.

Comment: Actually, polygamy is legal (or laws against it are not enforced) in many jurisdictions where English is spoken. See https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-where-polygamy-is-legal. Even in the "good ole USA", polygamy still exists in some areas without legal repercussions.  Just search YouTube for "polygamy in the USA".

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Yes, many drug dealers and murderers also get away with it without legal repercussions. Just search YouTube for "drug dealing in the USA."